# PHP (Editing and Deleting html file)

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I have learned in school is to input and display data using **file_put_content()**. But I can't figure it out how to edit/update or deleting the data inside.

My **"form.php"**

```
    <!--Form to the php script-->

<form action="foodscript.php"method="post">
  I love:<br>
  <input type="text" name="foodname" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After I input some food name, it's send to the file call **"foodscript.php"**

```
<?php
  //This is where my input data is being process to the txt file.
   $name= $_POST['foodname'];

  //This is where my data would be store in this file.
   $file= "foodhistory.html"; 

  //The function is begins to created new file and store my data on it.
  file_put_contents($file, $name . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

 ?>
```

So then, **foodhistory.html** has been created and store a data that I already enter on the form. The Data is call **"Sushi"** inside the **foodhistory.html**.

So my problem is how can I edit/update or delete my data "Sushi" using a new form that has the delete and edit button on it? If you guys have better idea how to do it, do you mind show me the process or ways? I'm just a student.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Don't store data in HTML, store it in a database.  You can edit/delete data there.  Given the question, what you should really be starting with is some tutorials on PHP/MySQL.

Comment: @David oh my school haven't taught this stage yet, but i would like to find it on the web.

Comment: Then the Google search term you're looking for is "PHP MySQL tutorial".

Comment: Alright, thanks David.

Comment: I disagree that the only way to do this is a database. Sure, any actual app would use that, but if you are just starting your first steps there's no need to shoot this down. The question has code, is clear.. I don't see why we shouldn't just help Teik, instead of saying "do it differently".

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you have to know which element to edit/delete, so the form must require the name of the food.

Given this, to edit/delete you can do **something similar**

```
<?php

$file = 'foodhistory.html';

$oldName = $_POST['oldname'];
$newName = $_POST['newname'];
$action  = $_POST['action']; // delete or edit

// this function reads the file and store every line in an array
$lines = file($file);

$position = array_search($oldName, $lines);

if($position) {
    exit('Food not found.');
}

switch($action) {
    case 'delete':
        unset($lines[$position]);
        break;
    case 'edit':
        $lines[$position] = $newName;
        break;
}

file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines)); // overwrite stuff on the file with fresh data
```

*PS: you obviously know that store data in an HTML file is not the right way... but I suppose this have something to do with school.*

Comment: Alright thanks Effe, I'll experiment it with your code and get back to you and figure out if its working.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a method for your form so the browser doesn't know how to send it.
Set the method attribute of the form to "post".
if it still doesn't work, try this code and tell us what you get:
`echo $_POST["foodname"];`

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. I actually forgot to put it on the questions.